# Get a PACK OF ELEMENTS with the same class prefix and/or same suffix and then update this PACK

Tags: javascript

Let's have an example:

```
<div class="gg-1"></div> // 1
<div class="gg-1"></div> // 1
<div class="gg-1"></div> // 1

<div class="gg-3"></div> // 3
<div class="gg-3"></div> // 3

<div class="gg-5"></div> // 5
<div class="gg-5"></div> // 5
```

How could I update those divs classes to get the below result?

```
<div class="gg-1"></div> // 1
<div class="gg-1"></div> // 1
<div class="gg-1"></div> // 1

<div class="gg-2"></div> // 2
<div class="gg-2"></div> // 2

<div class="gg-3"></div> // 3
<div class="gg-3"></div> // 3
```

Pure Javascript needed (JQuery as additional).

My function below could help you in getting elements by class with a prefix:

```
function scn$(container,selectorTag,prefix) {
    var items = [], myPosts = document.getElementById(container).getElementsByTagName(selectorTag);

    for (var i = 0; i < myPosts.length; i++) {
        // Omit Undefined Null Check
        if (myPosts[i].className.lastIndexOf(prefix,0) === 0) {
            items.push(myPosts[i]);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

So for now we can select our elements by `scn$('container','div','gg-')`.

What's next? Any ideas/clues?

Comment: You want to use Jquery or not use it?

Comment: JQuery version is welcome as additional one (for future, if I will move to it). For now I need pure Javascript with no frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach and let me know,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pmc3g/

```
(function() {

    function scn$(container, selectorTag, prefix) {
        var items = [],
            myPosts = document.getElementById(container).getElementsByTagName(selectorTag);

        var prevClass = null, curVal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < myPosts.length; i++) {
            var curClass = myPosts[i].className;
            // Omit Undefined Null Check
            if (curClass.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) === 0) {

                if (prevClass != curClass) {
                    prevClass = curClass;
                    curVal++;                   
                }

                myPosts[i].className = prefix + curVal;
                items.push(myPosts[i]);
                console.log(myPosts[i].className);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    scn$('container', 'div', 'gg-');

})();
```

Comment: Thank you! I've got how to do it!